# c# Reading from xls file - dates and numerics missing from dataset

Tags: c#, excel

When using the following code to read an xls file I am not getting the contents of any cell containing just dates or numbers. Cells with string data are returning fine.

```
var fileName = @"F:\excelfiles\3030497Testing.xls";
var connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source={0}; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;", fileName);
var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [mainDetails$]", connectionString);
var ds = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(ds, "SWinv");
DataTable data = ds.Tables["SWinv"];
foreach( DataRow row in data.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(row[3]); // has string data
    Console.WriteLine(row[11]); // has non-string data - EMPTY
}
```

When I substitute the data in column K (row[11]) with strings, it outputs these. Even when I alternate rows (String, non-string doesn't) so a condensed version would be:

```
column 3 | column 11 || output
hello row 1 | 9.5 || hello row 1
hello row 2 | b || hello row 2 b
hello row 3 | 21.1 || hello row 3
```

Also when I look at the dataset in the debugger the numbers are missing on the rows that should have them, but the string "b" is there on that row.

Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

I've also tried exceldatareader.codeplex.com, but that just returned no data at all in the dataset.

Thanks

Comment: Any difference in behavior if you add `;IMEX=1` to the Extended Properties in your connection string (i.e. `Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source={0}; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0; IMEX=1`)? (This setting forces the driver to read all values as text.)

Comment: thanks for that, connection string is now: var connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source={0}; Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0; IMEX=1\"", fileName);  And it's working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to read the column headers into the result set (using HDR=NO even though there is a header) and the column data is numeric, use IMEX=1 to avoid crash.

To always use IMEX=1 is a safer way to retrieve data for mixed data columns.

http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/